# Is a function call with missing argument semantic or syntax error?

Tags: testing, error-handling, syntax-error

I have recieved a comment saying that calling a function with incorrect number of arguments is a semantic error. I would say its a syntax error as the correct syntax is to provide as many parameters as requested using the delimiter.

And additional question: If a programmer does not understand the requirement properly and implement function that works differently than requested, is that a logic error? Is it considered to be an error at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A syntax error has to do only with conformance to the language.

A semantic error has to do with conformance to the API.

A function call that has the wrong number of parameters for the defined function is a semantic error.

As to your second question, at least by my definition, a logic error is when the code compiles and runs but does not function as expected, so I would call your example a logic error.  But I'm not sure this definition is universally accepted or obvious, so it may be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thank you, could you comment on the second question?

Answer (score 0):

An incorrect number of arguments on a method call is a syntax error. If the program doesn't do that the client expects is a error too. An error in the requeriments phase that is triggered to the code phase.

Comment: So, if its programmers fault, I would say its logical error but its not the same as if he understood but implemented something that works differently

Comment: This can be a specification error, a design error or a coding error.